# GitLab: How to Execute 1 Job per Runner Only

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We are currently implementing Test Execution of Test Suites using Gitlab's CI.

One of the issue we encountered is that it keeps using a runner even though it is being used by another job.

**Problem 1:**

- There are 3 available runners (different machines), config is already set to limit = 1 and request_concurrency = 1.
- Pipeline with 3 jobs running in parallel will be triggered.

**Result:** The 2 jobs will use 1 runner.

**Expectation:** The 3 jobs will use the 3 runners (1 job per runner).

---

**Problem 2:**

- Given the above conditions.
- Pipeline with 3 jobs running in parallel will be triggered twice.

**Result:** almost all jobs are running, executing multiple jobs in a runner.

**Expectation:** First pipeline should be running (1 job per runner) and second pipeline should be pending. 
Second pipeline's job/s will only be executed once done with first pipeline's job/s

Comment: What is your `concurrent` setting?

Comment: @sytech in each config file, there is a concurrent setup equals to 1. 

concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800
[[runners]]
  name = "..."
  url = "..."
  token = "..."
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "powershell"
  limit = 1
  request_concurrency = 1
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]

Comment: hmm... When I test this configuration with the latest version of GitLab runner, it works as expected. Are you sure you don't have other runners registered that are running the jobs? If you're on gitlab.com make sure you disabled shared runners or are using your own custom tags

Comment: @sytech yup I don't have other runners registered. When checking the job ID, the specific runner is specified there. I also noticed that it ran 2 jobs even though I already set concurrent, limit and request_concurrency to 1. Shared runners are disabled and I am also using 1 tag for all runners and my jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You must set `concurrent` to 1 in the [global settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section).

Also double check your configuration file to ensure you have not registered multiple runners on the same machine.